# Necessary tag for each question

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

Meta SE (and all in-site metas) requires you to use one of the tags [discussion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) [feature-request](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) [support](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) [bug](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) in every question you post.

Code Golf also has various challenge types and questions without a challenge type get closed. So can we have the same restriction here as well, wherein a question cannot be submitted unless it has one of the challenge type tags? ([code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) etc.)

Comment: The problem I see with this is that we don't have a fixed set of challenge types. OK, it doesn't happen all that often, but every time a new challenge type is created, we'd have to bug a dev to add it to the list...

Comment: @Dennis I imagine that such a challenge type would be discussed on meta and/or in the sandbox, so if it's deemed a good idea we'd at least have ample notice for bugging a dev.

Comment: @AlexA. I'm not saying it's a bad idea, but I do think it's a potential problem. That being said, I don't think we should expect any improvement of question quality from this. People post general programming questions on Meta SE all the time...

Comment: I swear this has been asked before, but I'm not going through the pain of searching on mobile to find it :/

Comment: @Dennis Agreed. I think the only situation it would really help is if someone was going to post a challenge without a winning criterion.

Comment: @IGoBest Found it

Comment: @Dennis Why can't mods be given power to modify site design (with community consensus)? Why must they wait for an SE developer?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code There are some things that the moderators can do, some that the SE Community Managers can do, and some that the developers have to do. Anything that involves code has to be handled by a developer; moderators don't have access to any of the system or site internals.